# How to skip 2 views when using navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In Xcode 5.0.2 I've created an iPhone app (the complete app [code is on GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth), please run `pod install` once - for `SDWebImage`), which displays a list of social networks (Facebook, Google+, etc.), then - in another view - an `UIWebView` displaying OAuth2 web page and then a third view with user avatar and details (first name, last name, etc.):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

(Here [the fullscreen screenshot of the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H1E9.png) shown above)

[image]

Before I display the user avatar and details in the last view, I save the user data to `NSUserDefaults`.

**My question is:** when the user starts the app the next time and there is user data in `NSUserDefaults` already - how can I skip the first 2 views and display (without any animation) the last view with those user details?

I've put the following code to the [AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/AppDelegate.m):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *key = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
    User *user = [User loadForKey:key];

    if (user) {
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        // XXX how to load the last view here? XXX
    }

    return YES;
}
```

and can see, that the user data is being loaded okay, but I don't understand how to jump to the last view (esp. because most of the UI is defined in the storyboard)?

**UPDATE:** I have tried following Tommy Alexander's suggestion (thanks!) with the following code in [AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/AppDelegate.m) (and also assigned `Details` StoryboardID to the last view):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *key = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
    User *user = [User loadForKey:key];

    if (user) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
        NSLog(@"XXX uvc=%@ user=%@", uvc, user);
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:uvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

and while the last view (the [UserViewController](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/UserViewController.h) with user avatar and details) seems to be instantiated okay, I get the following warning and the app doesn't jump to the last view:

```
MyAuth[3917:70b] XXX uvc=<UserViewController: 0x8acbac0> user=
VK
59751265
Alexander
Farber
1945522
http://cs319319.vk.me/v319319265/b7df/TnyKeffL_mU.jpg
0
MyAuth[3917:70b] Warning: Attempt to present <UserViewController: 0x8acbac0> on <UINavigationController: 0x8bb3a30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

**UPDATE 2:** When I move the above code to the `viewDidLoad` of the 1st view (the [MasterViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/MasterViewController.m), where the user can select a social network), then I get another warning:

```
MyAuth[1358:70b] XXX uvc=<UserViewController: 0x8a97430> user=
FB
597287941
Alexander
Farber
Bochum, Germany
http://graph.facebook.com/597287941/picture?type=large
0
MyAuth[1358:70b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x8a893e0>.
```

**UPDATE 3:** Thanks for the valuable answers! I've ended up using Leonty Deriglazov suggestion:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Master"];
    //UIViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    UIViewController *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"User"];

    User *user = [User load];
    NSArray *controllers = (user ? @[vc1, vc3] : @[vc1]);

    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [nc setViewControllers:controllers];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I guess you could add another segue from view 1 to view 4 and trigger i

Comment: Should I ctrl-drag the segue from the navigation controller to the last view?

Comment: I don't know..
maybe try this  
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

   UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];

    [self.window setRootViewController:uvc];

if not then make UINavigationController as rootViewController and make ivc as its rootViewController..

Hope that helps

Comment: See Update in my answer

Comment: @AlexanderFarber - I have posted an answer which always worked for me

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I've edited my answer to include info about your "UPDATE 2" problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a nutshell, the most straightforward solution is to use `-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]`.

You need to do the following to achieve what you want:

1. assign storyboard IDs to all your controllers,
2. instantiate all three view controller from the story board (this is lightweight as long as you don't do most of the initialisation work in controller's constructors)
3. put them into an array in the same order you have them in storyboard,
4. call `-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:]` with the array as the first argument.

That's it. The code in your `-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` might look like this (after checking your skipping condition of course):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAuth"]; //if you assigned this ID is storyboard
UIViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];  //if you assigned this ID is storyboard
UIViewController *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
NSArray *controllers = @[vc1, vc2, vc3];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navController setViewControllers:controllers];
```

If you paste just this to `-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`, you'll see that it works immediately.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be in fact the most straightforward and quick solution: I don't even have to load a VC, before I have to segue/present another VC.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Cheers! ;-) Feel free to reach out to me if you have any more questions — I'd be glad to help. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Breaking view hierarchy will always gives weird behavior.**


**By using below mentioned approach user will not be able to notice that LoginViewController is presented and then we have pushed to Detail screen.**

This approach always worked for me

**In LoginViewController.m File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

if (user) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UserViewController *userViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:listViewVC animated:YES];

    }
}
```

**In UserViewController.m File**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

if (user) {

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

}

}
```

Comment: This solutions spreads the knowledge of one particular navigation behaviour (skipping 2 views) across multiple controllers. Wouldn't it be getter to consolidate the knowledge of this feature in one place? It would be easier to write and easier to test/debug.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem starts with your initial Storyboard setup. I would use something like the below image.

I would make the `User View controller` my root view controller and present the login view controllers modally with or without animation.

Once the login succeeds it will be pretty convenient to dismiss the view controllers. And if the user logs out later on you'll just need to present the login view controllers again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to me, that the order of VCs is just a minor detail (like if you'll see short flashing of the table view on app startup or not). With my question I'm after **source code**, allowing me to push 2 VCs and jump to a 3rd one (whatever that will be).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this :

```
if (hasUser) {
    MyFirstViewController *firstViewController = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewControllerStoryboardId"];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerStoryboardId"];

    [myNavigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];
    [myNavigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This way you will not have any animations and the navigation stack will be respected.
Change the 'animated' boolean to play with the animation(s).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

According to your screen workflow, you have a navigation controller and other view controllers are pushed into it.

So, the logic is simple: if a user is cached **set details view controller as a root of your navigation view controller**, else do nothing (storyboard's default will be used).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;

    if (hasUser) {
        UIViewController *vc = [nc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
        nc.viewControllers = @[vc];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

UPDATE

In case you need to go back to previous view controllers (e.g. from details to table), you can  set the whole navigation hierarchy in navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
if (hasUser) {
    UIViewController *vc = [nc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
    [nc pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the user can't "Logout" to return to the TableView with the selection of social networks

Comment: Use the same technique and replace root of navigation controller with TableViewController in logout handler: `self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[tableViewController];`

Comment: I still have the minor problem then that the "Back" button isn't shown

Comment: In that case restore desired hierarchy by using `nc.viewControllers = @[tableViewController, detailsViewController]` or pushing view controllers to navigation stack. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your last UIViewController a StoryBoardID in the Attributes Inspector in IB.  Then, once you determine if you have a user in NSUSerDefault:

-Get a reference to your storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

-Insatiate an instance of your last view controller (remember to import your last view contorllers .h file):

```
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardID"];
```

-Present the VC:

```
[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the `Warning: Attempt to present <UserViewController: 0x8acbac0> on <UINavigationController: 0x8bb3a30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and the app doesn't skip to the last view - please see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

The best approach will be to use to UnwindSegue..

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)

**UPDATE IF COMMENT IS NOT CLEAR**

I don't know..

maybe try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
[self.window setRootViewController:uvc];
```

if not then make UINavigationController as rootViewController and make ivc as its rootViewController..

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, what to dismiss or unwind in my app? I am trying to skip the first 2 views and jump to the last view in the screenshot above...

Answer (score 1):

What I do in one of my apps, is I have an additional segue from the `rootViewController` to the screen I want to skip to (in your example, from MyAuth to Details). Then, when I show the `UINavigationController`, I also set a variable in the `rootViewController` specifying if I want to skip to another screen. Finally, in the `viewDidLoad:` of the view controller I do a check:

```
// Check if we want to skip to another screen
if (self.skipToDetails == YES) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailsView" sender:nil];
}
```

If you turn off animation for this segue in the storyboard file, the user won't see the first screen at all.

Also, you'll need to set `hidesBackButton` to `YES` in the Details screen.

**Edit:** The `"unbalanced calls to begin/end"` happens when you move to another VC (either push or modal) from the original (`rootViewController`) VC in `viewDidLoad:`. Moving the code to `viewDidAppear:` should help.

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander please check screenshot you can manage the controller like this:

[image]

And use following code in user view controller:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *key = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
User *user = [User loadForKey:key];

if (!user) {
 MasterViewController *loginController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MasterViewController"];
[self presentViewController:masterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *key = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
    User *user = [User loadForKey:key];

  UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    if (hasUser) {
        UIViewController *viewcon = [navcon.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
        [navcon pushViewController:viewcon animated:NO]; }   
}
else
   {
       UIViewController *viewcon = [navcon.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserViewController"];
       [navcon pushViewController:viewcon animated:NO];}
}
```